# How can i use an {{ }} into a function

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to call a function but one on mi parameters are in an api, so i need to use an {{}}
this is an example of mi code:

```
<button class="cssbuttons-io-button" (click)='goToPage("Players", {{team.TeamID}} )'> Informacion</button>
```

i tried this but doesnt work

```
<button class="cssbuttons-io-button" id = {{team.TeamID}} #teamid (click)='goToPage("Players", $event.target )'> Informacion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to pass a variable into a function from the html, you do not need interpolations ({{}}). You can just use the variable or API response as a parameter to the method. But you need to declare that variable using public access modifier. Below I have corrected your problem.

```html
<button class="cssbuttons-io-button" id = "{{team.TeamID}}" #teamid (click)="goToPage('Players', team.TeamID )">Informacion</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove your braces {{ }} and do the following :

```
<button class="cssbuttons-io-button" (click)='goToPage("Players", team.TeamID)'> Informacion</button>
```

Braces are only use to modify HTML content. Here you are using a javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
<button class="cssbuttons-io-button" [id] ="team.TeamID" #teamid (click)='goToPage("Players", $event.target )'> Informacion </button>
```